# Get value between a word and the linebreak in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, wildcard

I want to extract a value of string which is part of an XML structure with XSLT. Therefore I need to get the word in front of the colon as a node name and the word after the colon as a value for this node. The node name will be the same in every document, but the value will be various so I thought about using wildcards for extracting the value, but I didn't find out how to do that. Can you help me maybe?

```
    <mail>
        <body>
            Fruit: apple
            Vagetable: potato
            Animal: dog
        </body>
    </mail>
```

So the result should look like:

```
    <mail>
        <Fruit>apple</Fruit>
        <Vagetable>potato</Vagetable>
        <Animal>dog</Animal>
    </mail>
```

I'm working with XSLT 2.0

Comment: I suggest you just use substring-after(text(),': ')

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected result and also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Thanks @SiebeJongebloed, but how do I tell that the value ends in front of the linebreak?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've added your requests, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use *tokenize* function in template matching *mail* normalize *body* text before

```
<xsl:template match="mail">
    <xsl:variable name="strvalue" select="replace(./body/text(), '(^\n\s+)|(\n\s+$)', '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="strvalue" select="replace($strvalue, '\n\s+', '#')"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($strvalue, '#')">
            <xsl:variable select="tokenize(., ': ')" name="values"/>
            <!--<xsl:element name='{$values[1]}'>-->
            <xsl:element name="{replace($values[1], '[^\w]', '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$values[2]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

this part

```
<xsl:variable name="strvalue" select="replace(./body/text(), '(^\n\s+)|(\n\s+$)', '')"/>
<xsl:variable name="strvalue" select="replace($strvalue, '\n\s+', '#')"/>
```

transforms *body* text into string where lines are separated by # and save it in variable. the string from *body* then looks like

```
Fruit: apple#Vagetable: potato#Animal: dog
```

Comment: You are assuming that the value in a name/value pair will never contain a space.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks, you are right. i relied on the sample input in the question. corrected the answer

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but thanks for your solution. But I get an error in case if the node name contains a blank or a special character such as a bracket. Would it be possible to remove every blank and special character in the string through a underscore?

Comment: @Anonymus007 you can replace any non-word character with an underscore. I added a new line to my answer to demonstrate this and commented out the old one

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works, but there's one problem left. Since my starting document is automatically generated there are no indentions in the body element, which leads to the problem that only the first line can be edited all the other lines get lost in the result. Do you also have a solution therefore?

Comment: @Anonymus007 try replace second replace function  with  "replace($strvalue, '\n', '#')"

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mail">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(body, '&#10;')[normalize-space()]">
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before(., ': ')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ': ')"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's another:

```
<xsl:template match="mail">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="body" regex="^(.+): (.+)$" flags="m">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="{regex-group(1)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that both assume that the first part of each name/value pair is a valid element name.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but how would it work if there would be a blank in the element name? Such as:
Fruit type: apple

Comment: @Anonymus007 It would NOT work. As I said, you cannot create an element without supplying a valid element name. If you want, you can remove the space/s or [translate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) them to underscore/s - but that does not guarantee the result will be always  a valid element name. The real problem here is with the requirement, not with the method. If you want to be sure there won't be an error, then do not rely on the data provider to provide only specific data.